# How can I use a data connection from another book?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

Under Data -> Conections I have added a link to another excel worksheet. I'm trying to use some value from this new linked worksheet but I dont know how.

I'm researching this, because using [file] or indirect() is not enough.

How could I reference a cell from a defined data connection from another worksheet in a linked excel file?

Comment: Try the Existing connection item. Found on the Data tab -> Get External Data Group

Answer (score 0):

I fear that even a highly simplified answer to your question may require pages and pages of detail (for example, not counting the Connections icon set in the Ribbon, for Get External Data I have five icons in the standard Ribbon to choose from and one of these offers me seven choices) so merely an example:

In a new workbook, enter `666666` in Sheet2 B2, select B1:B2 and INSERT > Tables, Table, check My table has headers and OK. Save this workbook as WB1.xlsx, somewhere you can relocate it, and close it.
Open a new workbook and select A2 in Sheet1. DATA > Get External Data, Existing Connections. Browse for More…, find and select WB1.xlsx. Open. A Select Table window should then pop up and from it Select Sheet2$. OK. OK. In A3 of this new workbook you should now see `666666`.